# Breaking a loop from outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have a data set, over which I iterate and run a fairly heavy operation on each element. To prevent the browser from freezing, I've set a timeout of 0ms. While the browser doesn't freeze, the calculation can take a good few seconds depending on user input. Here's the code:

```
function calculation(){
    $.each(data,function(key,value){
        setTimeout(function(){
            doTheHeavyLifting(value);
        },0);
    });
}
```

Now, the problem is, that I want to stop the previous calculation if the user requests to run the calculation again with new values.

I tried defining a `continueCalculating` boolean outside the function, and setting that to `false` in `runCalculation()` before calling `calculation()`, and inside `calculation()` resetting it back to `true`. Here's the modified code:

```
var continueCalculating=false;

function runCalculator(){
    continueCalculating=false;
    calculation();
}

function calculation(){
    continueCalculating=true;
    $.each(data,function(key,value){
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(continueCalculating){
                doTheHeavyLifting(value);
            }else{
                console.log("Abort the mission!");
                return false;
            }
        },0);
    });
}
```

Well, that didn't do the trick, and in retrospect was a pretty silly idea anyway. So, next I tried also clearing all the timeouts.  Here's the modified code:

```
var continueCalculating=false;
var operationQueue=[];

function runCalculator(){
    continueCalculating=false;
    $.each(operationQueue, function(k,v){
        clearTimeout(v);
    });
    calculation();
}

function calculation(){
    continueCalculating=true;
    $.each(data,function(key,value){
        operationQueue.push(setTimeout(function(){
            if(continueCalculating){
                doTheHeavyLifting(value);
            }else{
                console.log("Abort the mission!");
                return false;
            }
        },0));
    });
}
```

Well, that didn't yield any results either.

I know `$.each` is slower than `for`, but there are only about a couple dozen items to iterate over, so it certainly isn't the bottle neck here. I'm not looking for ways to optimize this code, I just need to stop an on-going calculation. Is this possible?

Comment: You shouldn't be using a loop here at all. If you want to make the processing of the items abortable, you should process one item at a time and "give time" in between for other code to abort the process. You basically want a recursive function that uses `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 2):

You should iterate asynchronously:

```js
var data = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"end"];
function doTheHeavyLifting(value) {
  console.log(value);
}
function calculation(data) {
  var key = 0, timer;
  (function loop() {
    if(key < data.length) {
      doTheHeavyLifting(data[key]);
      key++;
      timer = setTimeout(loop, 1e3);
    }
  })();
  return {stop: function() { clearTimeout(timer) } };
}
var calc = calculation(data);
document.querySelector('#stop').onclick = calc.stop;
```

```html
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
```

Comment: This is really cool. I've always used a global flag that the async function periodically checks to accomplish something like this, but here you avoid both polluting the global scope, and having to check the flag during each loop, and your example is clear and easy to follow. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.queue()`, `$.Deferred()`, `.promise()`

```js
// check at `if` condition within deferred
var stop = false;
$("button").on("click", function() {
  // clear `"calculation"` queue at `click` event at `button` element
  $.queue(data, "calculation", []);
  // set `stop` to `true` at `click` event at `button`
  stop = true;
});
// `data`
var data = Array(100).fill(0).map((v, k) => k);

function doTheHeavyLifting(val) {
  console.log(val);
  // return `.promise()` when process within `doTheHeavyLifting` completes
  return $("body").append("\n" + val).promise()
}

function calculation() {
   $.queue(data, "calculation", $.map(data, function(value, index) {
     return function(next) {    
       return new $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
         setTimeout(function() {
           if (!stop) {
             dfd.resolve(doTheHeavyLifting(value))
           } else {
             dfd.rejectWith(
               $.queue(data, "calculation")
               , ["queue stopped at " + index]
             );
           }
         },0)
       })
       // iterate next item in `data`
       .then(next)
       // do stuff if `"calculation"` queue is empty array
       .fail(function(message) {
         console.log(message
                     , "calculation queue:", this);
         alert(message);             
       })
     }
   }));
   // start queue
   $.dequeue(data, "calculation");
}

calculation();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<button>stop calculation</button>
```